# What do the numbers in the preferred IUPAC name for ascorbic acid mean?

Tags: organic-chemistry, nomenclature, heterocyclic-compounds

If I look up the IUPAC name of [ascorbic acid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ascorbic_acid), I find this: **(5*R*)-[(1*S*)-1,2-Dihydroxyethyl]-3,4-dihydroxyfuran-2(5*H*)-one**.

I am used to numbering of molecules in a way like the `3,4-dihydroxyfuran` part in this molecule name. But now what I want to know is: what do the 5R, 1S and 5H parts signify?

For the 5H I came up with this: [furan](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Furan) has two double bonds, so the H might signify that this is not the case any more, because if there is an extra H at the fifth position, this would be impossible. This can be seen in the IUPAC name of [2-furanone](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2-Furanone): `5H-furan-2-one`. I don't know though if this assumption is correct, also because in `5H-furan-2-one` the 5H is before the furan part and in `3,4-dihydroxyfuran-2(5H)-one` it is after (shouldn't it be `2(3,4-dihydroxy-5H)-furanone` anyway?)

Fact is that I can't find an explanation for the 5R, nor the 1S (as I see no sulfur). Could anyone explain me these weird molecule numberings?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The numbering of *(R)*-5-[*(S)*-1,2-dihydroxyethyl]-3,4-dihydroxyfuran-2(5​*H*)-one has four parts:

### 1) Numbering of the furan ring

[image]

### 2) Numbering of the ethyl side chain

[image]

### 3) Stereodescriptors *R* and *S*

[image]

### 4) Italicized element symbols

The italic element symbol *H* denotes indicated or added hydrogen.

Comment: Using the PIN mentioned in the question would be much nicer ;)